# Should I index a bit field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I remember reading at one point that indexing a field with low cardinality (a low number of distinct values) is not really worth doing.  I admit I don't know enough about how indexes work to understand why that is.

So what if I have a table with 100 million rows in it, and I am selecting records where a bit field is 1? And let's say that at any point in time, there are only a handful of records where the bit field is 1 (as opposed to 0).  Is it worth indexing that bit field or not? Why?

Of course I can just test it and check the execution plan, and I will do that, but I'm also curious about the theory behind it.  When does cardinality matter and when does it not?

Comment: Is this a common query? It may be worth it when looking for the "handful" of records but won't help you much on the other rows. Are there other ways to identify the data?

Comment: While I don't think I would index JUST a bit column by itself, it is very common to include bit columns as part of a compound index. A simple example would be an index on ACTIVE, LASTNAME instead of just lastname, when your application is almost always looking for active customers.

Comment: "I remember reading at one point that indexing a field with low cardinality (a low number of distinct values) is not really worth doing" That because SQL Server will almost always find its more efficient to just do a table-scan than to read the index. So basically your index will never get used and it's a waste to maintain it. As others have said it might be ok in a compound index.

Comment: Cardinality is one factor, the other is how well does the index divide your data. If you have about half 1s and half 0s, then it will help. (Assuming that that index is a better path to choose than some other index). However, how often are you inserting and updating? Adding indexes for SELECT performance also hurt the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE performance, so keep that in mind. I would say, if the 1s to 0s (or vice versa) isn't better than 75% to 25%, don't bother.

Comment: I would disagree. If your distribution is 50/50, then you would never use the index, as it would just be quicker to do a table scan.  However, if you only have 5, 1 values, and 1 million 0 values, it would be very likely to use the index when searching for 1.

Comment: On its own, no as it results in very little selectivity. As part of a compound index. quite possibly but only after other equality columns.

Comment: In the example you gave, I would be more inclined to put LastName first. It depends on the specific query workload, but in general having the more selective column first, means the index is more likely to be used.

Comment: In case you haven't read it, Jason Massie wrote an article recently that discussed this very topic. http://statisticsio.com/Home/tabid/36/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/302/Never-Index-a-BIT.aspx Edit: New article location - http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/never-index-a-bit

Comment: very late answer... Yes, it can be [useful according to SQL CAT team](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2011/01/31/sql-server-indexing-using-a-low-selectivity-bit-column-first-can-be-the-best-strategy.aspx)

Comment: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2014/02/17/dba-myths-an-index-on-a-bit-column-will-never-be-used.aspx

Comment: I came across this question wondering the same thing because I had a similar dilemma. Decided to do a comparison where I was working with about 75million rows. Query was about taking 10 seconds and as soon as I added the index it dropped down to a few milliseconds. Also ran it with "set statistics io on" and saw that the logical read decreased significantly. I tested all this with cache turned off. I would say test it out for yourself and find out.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Consider what an index is in SQL - and index is really a chunk of memory pointing at other chunks of memory (i.e. pointers to rows).  The index is broken into pages so that portions of the index can be loaded and unloaded from memory depending on usage.

When you ask for a set of rows, SQL uses the index to find the rows more quickly than table scanning (looking at every row).

SQL has clustered and non-clustered indexes.  My understanding of clustered indexes is that they group similar index values into the same page.  This way when you ask for all the rows matching an index value, SQL can return those rows from a clustered page of memory.  This is why trying to cluster index a GUID column is a bad idea - you don't try to cluster random values.

When you index an integer column, SQL's index contains a set of rows for each index value.  If you have a range of 1 to 10, then you would have 10 index pointers.  Depending on how many rows there are this can be paged differently.  If your query looks for the index matching "1" and then where Name contains "Fred" (assuming the Name column is not indexed), SQL gets the set of rows matching "1" very quickly, then table scans to find the rest.

So what SQL is really doing is trying to reduce the working set (number of rows) it has to iterate over.

When you index a bit field (or some narrow range), you only reduce the working set by the number of rows matching that value.  If you have a small number of rows matching it would reduce your working set a lot.  For a large number of rows with 50/50 distribution, it might buy you very little performance gain vs. keeping the index up to date.

The reason everyone says to test is because SQL contains a very clever and complex optimizer that may ignore an index if it decides table scanning is faster, or may use a sort, or may organize memory pages however it darn well likes.

Comment: So it sounds like if I only ever have a handful of rows where the bit field is 1 (for example keeping track of "IsProcessed"), then an index would be good because it will order them by value and then be able to select the small working set very quickly. If you agree, add that and I will accept it.

Comment: What I mean in my previous comment is that this statement:

"When you index a bit field (or some narrow range), you only reduce the working set in half"

is not true if the distribution is heavily  weighted toward one value. But I like the rest of your answer, so if you fix that, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done.  I was thinking that for a million rows, a bit field would have 50% distribution, but you are right that for a particular problem space it could reduce the working set a lot.

Comment: It's worthwhile to look at execution plans with and without the index, and see if the index is being used and if it actually reduces the cost of your queries. Easy and scientific!

Comment: What about indexing a bit field + another field? Eg. in a web activity log, one would index the timestamp, but another useful index might be on a bit field "IsHTTPS" + timestamp, to quickly view all https actions. Would that also be inefficient?

Comment: I remember back in the day of SQL Server Enterprise Manager, for some reason the DWH people in my company using its table designer used to create clustered PKs on GUID columns, I believe it had to do with some of its defaults during table creation and their lack of knowledge about clustered indexes.

Answer (score 26):

I just came across this question by way of another. Assuming that your statement that only a handful of the records assume the value of 1 (and that those are the ones you're interested in), then a filtered index could be a good choice. Something like:

```
create index [IX_foobar] on dbo.Foobar (FooID) where yourBitColumn = 1
```

This will create a substantially smaller index that the optimizer is smart enough to use when that is a predicate in your query.

Comment: It's worth noting that the predicate in the query must be hard-coded to the value in the filtered index. If you pass the value in a parameter `yourBitColumn = @value`, then the optimizer can't determine whether the filtered index is usable.

Comment: There are ways around this, but you're right; the optimizer needs a guarantee at compilation time that the values for any predicates matching the filtered index predicate are static/invariant since it's the optimizer's job to create a general plan that will work for *any* set of parameters.

Comment: Big fan of using filtered indexes for the "handful" scenario, vs. indexing the whole bit column in general. Also worthy to mention that it can really help the optimizer if you add the filter column to the end of the key (especially if the predicate can differ). This is mentioned [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16#Restrictions).

Answer (score 11):

100-million records with only a few having the bit field set to 1? Yes, I would think indexing the bit field would definitely speed up querying the bit=1 records. You should get logarithmic search time from the index and then only touch the few pages with bit=1 records. Otherwise, you'd have to touch all pages of the 100-million record table.

Then again, I'm definitely not a database expert and could be missing something important.

Answer (score 11):

If your distribution is pretty known and unbalanced, like 99% of the rows are bit = 1 and the 1% are bit = 0, when you do a WHERE clause with bit = 1, a full table scan will be around the same time as the index scan.  If you want to have a fast query where bit = 0, the best way I know is create a filtered index, adding a clause WHERE bit = 0.  That way, that index will only store the 1% row.  Then doing a WHERE bit = 0 will simply let the query optimizer choose that index, and all rows from it will be bit = 0.  You also have the benefit to have a very small amount of disk space required compare a full index on the bit.

Comment: If 99% of the rows are bit=1, the optimizer should ignore the index and do a table scan. Using the index will actually be _worse_ than a table scan, at least on a rotational drive, more I/O and non-consecutive reads from the disk. The filtered index (Postgres equivalent: partial index) is the way to go. I guess because it is years after the question, this answer didn't get the votes it deserved.

Answer (score 8):

While I don't think I would index JUST a bit column by itself, it is very common to include bit columns as part of a compound index.

A simple example would be an index on ACTIVE, LASTNAME instead of just lastname, when your application is almost always looking for active customers.

Comment: In the example you gave, I would be more inclined to put LastName first. It depends on the specific query workload, but in general having the more selective column first, means the index is more likely to be used.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if an index has the effects you desire: **test and test again.**

In general you don't want an index that doesn't narrow down your table enough, because of the cost to maintain an index. (cost > profit). But if the index in your case will cut the table in half, you may gain something but putting it on the table. It all depends on the exact size/structure of your table and how you are using it (number of reads/writes).

Answer (score 2):

Of course it worths, especially if you need to retrieve the data by that value. It would be similar to using a sparse matrix instead of using a normal matrix.

Now with SQL 2008 you can use partitioning functions, and you are able to filter the data that goes in an index. The disadvantage for earlier versions would be that the index would be made for all the data, but this can be optimized by storing the interesting values in a separate file group.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you'll want to measure this.  I don't recall where I've read this, but a column needs to have very high cardinality (around 95%) in order for an index to be effective. Your best test for this would be to build the index and examine the execution plans for the 0 and 1 values of the BIT field. If you see an index seek operation in the execution plan then you know that your index will be used.

Your best course of action would be to test the with a basic SELECT * FROM table WHERE BitField = 1; query and slowly build out the functionality from there step by step until you have a realistic query for your application, examining the execution plan with every step to make sure that the index seek is still being utilized. Admittedly, there is no guarantee that this execution plan will be used in production, but there is a good chance that it will be.

Some information can be found on the [sql-server-performance.com forums](http://sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/indexing_low_sel_cols_p2.aspx) and in the referenced [article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/indexing_low_sel_cols_p2.aspx)

Comment: It's not such much the cardinality of the column as a whole that matters.  It is the selectivity of the WHERE clause.  So if there are few columns with value 1, it can still be good to index.  If it's 50/50 (e.g. male/female) then not so worth it.

Answer (score 2):

"I remember reading at one point that indexing a field with low cardinality (a low number of distinct values) is not really worth doing"

That because SQL Server will almost always find its more efficient to just do a table-scan than to read the index. So basically your index will never get used and it's a waste to maintain it. As others have said it might be ok in a compound index.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to make querying for records where the bit field value equals '1' faster you might try an indexed view of your base table which only contains records where your bit field equals '1'.  In enterprise edition if a query could make use of an indexed view instead of a specified table to improve query performance it will use the view.  In theory this would increase the speed of select queries which only look for records with a bit field value of '1'.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/impprfiv.mspx

All this assumes you are Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Enterprise.  The same might apply to 2008, I'm not familiar with that version.

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* index a bit field in SQL Server 2000, as was indicated in the Books Online at the time:

> **bit**
>
> Integer data type 1, 0, or NULL.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Columns of type **bit** cannot
> have indexes on them.

Yes, if you have only a handful of rows, out of millions, an index will help. But if you want to do it in this case you need to make the column a `tinyint`.

**Note**: Enterprise Manager will not let you create an index on a bit column. If you wish you can still manually create an index on a bit column:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Users_IsActiveUsername ON Users
(
   IsActive,
   Username
)
```

But SQL Server 2000 will not actually use such an index - running a query where the index would be a perfect candidate, e.g.:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Username 
FROM Users
WHERE IsActive = 0
```

SQL Server 2000 will do a table scan instead, acting as though the index doesn't even exist. If you change the column to a tinyint SQL Server 2000 *will* do an index seek. Also, the following non-covered query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Users
WHERE IsActive = 0
```

It will perform an index seek, followed by a bookmark lookup.

---

SQL Server 2005 does have limited support for indexes on bit columns. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Username 
FROM Users
WHERE IsActive = 0
```

will cause an index seek through the covering index. But the non-covered case:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Users
WHERE IsActive = 0
```

will not cause an index seek followed by a bookmark lookup, it will perform a table scan (or clustered index scan), rather than performing the index seek followed by a bookmark lookup.

Verified by experimentation and direct observation.

Comment: FYI - SQL Server 2005 Management Studio does let you do it.

Comment: My copy of SQL Server 2000 let me set an index on a bit column.

Comment: My copy of SQL Server 2000 doesn't let me set an index on a bit column.

Answer (score 1):

On its own, no as it results in very little selectivity. As part of a compound index. quite possibly but only after other equality columns.

Answer (score 1):

very late answer...

Yes, it can be [useful according to SQL CAT team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/10/23/sqlcat-com-ebook-downloads.aspx) (updated, has been consolidated)

Comment: The link appears to be dead now.  However, that post appears to have been consolidated along with several others in an [e-book](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/B/0FBFAA46-2BFD-478F-8E56-7BF3C672DF9D/SQLCAT's%20Guide%20to%20Relational%20Engine.pdf).  The referenced section begins on page 86.  The e-book can be downloaded from [SQLCAT.com eBooks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/10/23/sqlcat-com-ebook-downloads.aspx) under the link "SQLCAT's Guide to Relational Engine".

Answer (score 0):

**measure** response time before and after and see if it is worthwhile; theoretically it should improve performance for queries using the indexed fields but it really depends on the distribution of true/false values and the other fields involved in the queries that you're concerned about

Answer (score 0):

Is this a common query?  It may be worth it when looking for the "handful" of records but won't help you much on the other rows.  Are there other ways to identify the data?

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality is one factor, the other is how well does the index divide your data. If you have about half 1s and half 0s, then it will help. (Assuming that that index is a better path to choose than some other index). However, how often are you inserting and updating? Adding indexes for SELECT performance also hurt the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE performance, so keep that in mind.

I would say, if the 1s to 0s (or vice versa) isn't better than 75% to 25%, don't bother.

Comment: I would disagree. If your distribution is 50/50, then you would never use the index, as it would just be quicker to do a table scan.  However, if you only have 5, 1 values, and 1 million 0 values, it would be very likely to use the index when searching for 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ian Boyd is correct when he says that you could not do it via Enterprise Manager for SQL 2000 (see his note regarding creating it throught T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be smart here to query, you must know the load value on your column if the load of true is more in your system and you want to check all the true values writ  your query to check not false.. it will help alot, it just trick.