# comparion/performance of database field as int vs char(1)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, optimization

does one perform better over the other in terms of indexing/quering etc ?

e.g. declaring a column as 
active Char(1) with 'Y' / 'N' values 
vs
is_active  tinyint with values 1 / 0

Anecdotally speaking most places it seems people prefer to use char(1)
whereas my tendency is to declare them as tinyint/int not the least because it's easy to use/type

Any real performance comparisons out there ?
I recall something like a binary value index in oracle ( bitmapped index or some such ) - is there something similar in sql2005/sql2008/...?

UPDATE - in response to some of the comments below, performance would be defined in terms of index query / updates, storage is irrelevant considering it's cheap enough

semantics too are not relevant !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any column with char/varchar has the potential of sending you through all of the extra internal code for the semantics of letter translation / collation, etc. during indexing, equality tests, etc.

So, a number is better. And **bit** is the best solution for the case you describe--it stores only a 0 or 1 (and is nullable of course).

SQL Server *does* collapse bit fields internally to store up to 8 bit fields in each byte, so it is more efficient than tinyint if you have multiple bit fields:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: bit fields cannot be indexed...hence useless for quering....so semantics issues would arise for tinyint/smallint/int/bigint columns too !

Comment: You *can* index bit fields, it just does very little good because there are only two values! If you store two values in some other sort of column and index it, that index will perform just as poorly.

Comment: More info:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server

Comment: hmm, wasn't aware of that, must be new in sql2008

Comment: true, as a standalone indexing bit fields is not useful but as part of a composite key, they can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are no integer or logical data types in Oracle.  A bitmapped index is something different that is derived from column values of other datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if all the RDBMS products supported a Boolean datatype.  Then we could kill off this question.  As it is, it comes down to personal taste.  I find it easier to understand ...

```
if is_active = 'Y' then
```

... rather than ...

```
if is_active = 1 then
```

But if I spoke French instead of English I would want it to be O/N, whereas the 1/0 implementation is universal.  The key thing is to use a single convention throughout the system.

With regards to performance, if your biggest bottleneck is the difference between char(1) and integer then I salute your tuning prowess.

Comment: not a bottleneck as the system is not implemented yet...however as this is for a real-time risk mgmt app  every millisecond boost would be nice