# Sql Server Index on Bit fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, indexing

I am using Sql Server 2000 and want to know why we can not create index on bit fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I index a bit field in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a limitation of the product. SQL Server 2005+ does allow this.

Because of the [Tipping Point](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx) a single column `bit` index is unlikely to be very useful unless the values are heavily skewed (a scenario for which filtered indexes in 2008 can help)

Still - could be useful as part of a composite covering index though.

Comment: Yes @Marin I am having the same scenario, it is a huge table where I wanted to build composite index but sql 2000 does not do it. Need to find out other alternates!!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

<s>I would guess this is by design.</s> A bit field can only have 1 of 2 values, so it would not be selective enough for an index to be useful.