# MS-SQL 2012 - indexing Bit field

Tags: sql-server

On an MS-SQL 2012, does it makes sense to index a "Deleted" BIT field if one is going to always use it on the Queries  (ie. SELECT xx FROM oo WHERE Deleted = 0)

Or does the fact that a field is BIT, already comes with some sort of auto index for performance issues??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I index a bit field in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

When you index a bit field which consist of either 1,0 or some limited values, you are actually reducing the number of rows matching that value. For fewer records this may work well but for large number of data it may help you in performance gain.

You can include bit columns as part of compound index

Index on bit field could be really helpful in scenarios where there is a large discrepancy between the number of 0's and 1's, and you are searching for the the smaller of the two.

Comment: In my case where on the User table I have the DELETED (bit) field, what would you suggest?

Comment: You would likely never just ask for all deleted/undeleted records, you would like ask for USER = X and Deleted = 0 so it would be useless as a standalone index but very important as a compond index.

Answer (score 1):

indexing a bit field will be pretty useless, under must conditions, because the selectivity is  so low.  An index scan on a large table is not going to be better than a table scan.  If there are other conditions you can use to create filtered indices you could consider that.

If this field is changing the nature of the logic in such a way that you will always need to consider it in the predicate, you might consider splitting the data into other tables when reporting.

Comment: Interesting concept ...so what would you suggest for a "Deleted" field on a User Table?

Comment: The main `Users` table would still have the field, but you would also maintain a table of `ActiveUsers`.  This would normally just be a reference to the `Users` table by key.  Keep in mind that for small tables this will be absurd, knowing that this is users I can only assume it will not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Whether to index a bit field depends on several factors which have been adequately explained in the answer to this question.  [Link to 231125](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, selectivity is the key. However, if you're always searching on one value or another and that value *is* highly selective, consider using a filtered index.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put out on the front of your clustered index? If deletes are incremental, you'd have to turn your fill factor down, but they're probably daily, right? And you have way more deleted records than undeleted records? And, as you say, you only ever query undeleted records. So, yes.  Don't just index that column.  Cluster on it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful as a part of composite index, when the bit-column is at the first position in the index. But if you suppose to use it only for selectitn one value (select .... where deleted=1 and another_key=?; but never deleted=0) then create index on another_key with filter:

```
create index i_another on t(another_key) where deleted=1
```

If the bit-column should be the last in the composite index then the occurrence in index is useless. However You can include it for better performace:

```
create index i_another on t(another_key) include(deleted)
```

Then the DB engine gets the value along with reading index and doesn't need to pick up it from base table page.