# Will replacing the primary key clustered index with another index cause issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, indexing

Using SQL Server 2008/2012, I currently have two tables, like so:

```
tblAccount (accountID BIGINT, accountActive BIT)

tblSite (siteID BIGINT, accountID BIGINT, siteActive BIT)
```

Currently, `accountID` on `tblAccount` is the primary key and a clustered index.

And `siteID` on `tblSite` is the primary key and clustered index

Most of my queries will take the form:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <some table> X
INNER JOIN tblSite s ON s.siteID = X.siteID
INNER JOIN tblAccount a ON a.accountID = s.accountID
WHERE 
   x.<field> = SOMETHING  
   AND a.accountActive = 1 
   AND s.siteActive = 1
```

My understanding, is that to optimise these queries, it would be better to put new clustered indexes on `tblAccount` and `tblSite`.

Something like:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ON tblAccount (accountActive,accountID) WITH .....

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ON tblSite (siteActive,siteID) WITH .....
```

Obviously, to do this, I'll have to drop the PK clustered indexes for both tables.

Is there a possibility that this could cause issues further down the line? As I'm assuming (taking the account table) the table is now optimised for

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAccount 
WHERE accountID = X 
  AND accountActive = Y
```

so just doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAccount 
WHERE accountID = X
```

will be highly unoptimised?

There are two other indexes I've created on the account table, I don't know how much these will have an impact on the above indexes & queries:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_account_session 
    ON tblAccount (accountSessionKey,accountActive,accountAffirmed,accountLastAction)     
    INCLUDE (accountID) 
    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF,SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON,FILLFACTOR=80)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_account_login 
    ON tblAccount (accountEmail,accountPassword,accountAffirmed,accountActive) 
    INCLUDE (accountID,accountSaltHash) 
    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF,SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON,FILLFACTOR=80)
```

I've put these on to optimise the authentication stored procedures.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Changing the clustered index will change how your table works, currently `accountID` is unique, but if you make the clustered index on accountID  and Active you could end up with 2 records for the same accountID (one active, one not). The benefit of indexing bit fields is very much dependent on your data distribution. What proportion of your accounts are active?

Comment: If you have an index on `(AccountID, AccountActive)`, then this index can be used for queries against the `AccountID` alone, too - no performance penalty there. But the **clustering index** is the index that determines the physical layout of your table, and is automatically included in **all** other nonclustered indexes - I would make sure it's **as small as possible**, and also **unique** - otherwise SQL Server will add "hidden" uniquefiers to your indexes - not a good thing!

Comment: @GarethD - The majority of the accounts and sites will be active, how should the index be adapted for that?

Comment: @marc_s - So when creating indexes e.g. CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_account_session 
    ON tblAccount (accountSessionKey,accountActive,accountAffirmed,accountLastAction)     
    INCLUDE (accountID) 
    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF,SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON,FILLFACTOR=80)
is the INCLUDE (accountID)?

Comment: I personally would not bother indexing it if the majority of the accounts are active, [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231423/1048425) for more information on indexing bit fields.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the clustered index will change how your table works, currently `accountID` is unique, but if you make the clustered index on accountID  and Active you could end up with 2 records for the same accountID (one active, one not). So in order to change the clustering key and also keep AccountID unique you would also need to add a unique constraint (or unique index).

If you will be querying active accounts/sites most of the time, and you feel that the performance is a problem, I would opt for an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx), and keep your clustered index on accountID as it is.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ActiveAccount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  AccountID, <Columns>
    FROM    dbo.tblAccount 
    WHERE   ActiveAccount = 1;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_ActiveAccount_AccountID 
    ON dbo.ActiveAccount (AccountID);
GO
```

And also a similar indexed view for Site, so your query becomes:

```
SELECT  <columns>
FROM    ActiveAccount A (NOEXPAND)
        INNER JOIN ActiveSite s (NOEXPAND)
            ON a.accountID = s.accountID;
```

But when you want all accounts/sites not just active ones you can query the main table rather than the indexed view.

Be aware though that the cost of maintaining this indexed view *could* outweigh the benefits you gain by selecting from it, as mentioned in a comment it depends on the cardinality of your data, and the frequency of which you need to query only active accounts/sites.

Comment: Wow, there is just so much to think about... just when I think I have a good understanding of SQL Server, more stuff uncovers itself. I saw someone trying to do an inner join like mine and the answer on Stack Overflow was to change the Clustered Index. So when is it a good idea to change the clustered index? And when is it a good idea to use a indexed view?

Comment: In Short, the clustering key should be mostly, if not entirely considered outside of the context of any queries, remember the clustered index is your table data. The main factor should be the table data itself. [This article](http://www.sqlconsulting.com/news1110.htm) gives some guides on choosing the correct clustering key. Once chosen (correctly) there shouldn't really be any need to change it (unless requirements change). For query optimisation I would always look to nonclustered indexes, or indexed views for optimisation, rather than changing the table itself.