# Cloning Stored Procedures for partitioned tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am in the process of partitioning a very large (> 20 million rows) table into logically partitioned tables which will result in older, less frequently viewed and updated, rows being split into multiple tables.  Essentially a manual approach to the Enterprise level feature of automated table partitioning.

We have two tables, Product and Cost.  Currently all Product records record their Costs in a central table, resulting in millions of rows.  The plan is to segregate Cost into many tables (Cost1, Cost2, Cost3, ...) to reduce the number of rows in each table, and each Product record will know which table to gather it's own costs from.

Currently all INSERTs into this table are handled through a Stored Procedure (lets call this "InsertCosts").  Within the procedure, currently the Cost table is referenced.

We have two options for how to proceed:

1. Do we work out some dynamic SQL within a single stored procedure which will look at the Product we are inserting for, and run a SQL Exec string to insert the record? The stored proc is 500+ lines long, to add context to the complexity of the amount of work it may need to do.
2. Or - do we allow the application to clone the stored proc many times, so we have InsertCosts1, InsertCosts2, InsertCosts3... and these are all fixed procedures.

My gut instinct says that we should go with Option 2.  The risk, however, is whether this is a scalable solution? We can revert back to option 1 fairly easily, and when it comes to creating the cloned Stored Procs this will also be simple for us to do so I don't any complexity of doing this to detract form the answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans and considered better indexes before going down the partitioning route?

Comment: Thanks Tanner - yes this is something we have been looking at in parallel.  Due to the nature of how the application works, however, with products that are 'finished' very rarely being accessed, whereas those which are 'active' requiring lots more writes, the nature of the data seems quite different.  This is why we think that the 'older' data should be separated out from the 'newer' data...

Comment: If you have a bit field to filter 'finished'/'active' rows, this might be a useful read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server. It details how adding indexes on bit columns where the value of the bit column can reduce the number of rows required to be returned can improve performance. But you'd have to test it to prove it's worth like any performance tuning.