# Simple SELECT/WHERE query slow. Should I index a BIT field?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, performance

The following query takes 20-25 seconds to run

```
SELECT * from Books WHERE IsPaperback = 1
```

Where `IsBundle` is a `BIT` field. There's about 500k rows, and about 400k currently have this field set.

I also have a `BIT` field called `IsBundle` and only 900 records have this set. Again, execution time is about 20-25 seconds.

How can I speed up such a simple query?

Comment: How long does it take to run without that where clause?

Comment: Replace `SELECT *` with the columns you actually need. Indexing the Bit column will help but if you are returning all the columns in a table it will have to read each page from start to end.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with indexing a `Bit` field, but how much data are you selecting?  It could be taking a long time to return simply because you are selecting a large amount of data.  How long does it take to come back without the `Where` filter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4):

Indexing a bit column will result in two parts, true and false. If the data is split 50/50 the gain will be 'some'. When it is 90/10 and you query the 10 part, yes it will make a difference.

You should first narrow down your result set column wise. Then, if you see you just need a few columns, and you execute this query a lot, you could even include those few fields in the index. Then there is no need for a lookup in the table itself.

Comment: @Rick: Did this answer your question or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would implicitly call out the columns,

```
select
     field1
   , field2
   , field3
from books
where IsPaperback = 1;
```

this seems to be a small thing, but when you use star (*) for column selection, the DB has to look up the column names prior to actually performing the call.

do you have a index on IsPaperback ? that would impact the above query more than having an index on the IsBundle

if you had a condition of IsBundle = 1 then i would think that would be need for an index on that field.

Answer (score -3):

Add an Index for `IsPaperback`

Try making it an int, or tinyint.  The latest processors actually process 32 bit words faster than bytes.

**This query should take no more than a couple of milliseconds.**

You should not have a separate column for IsPaperback and IsBundle.  It should be a Type column where Paperback and Bundle are the vaules.

Before the query set profiling on

```
SET profiling = 1
```

After the query show profiles:

```
SHOW PROFILES
```

**It seems there are some out there that do not believe this query should take only a few milliseconds.**

### For those that down voted this answer
 without understanding what I said was true.

I found a table "cities" with **332,127 Records**

In this table **Russia has 929 cities**

These benchmarks were preformed on a GoDaddy Server IP 50.63.0.80
This is a GoDaddy Virtual Dedicated Server
On average I find sites hosted on GoDaddy to have the worst performance.

```
$time = microtime(true); 
$results = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `cities` WHERE `country` LIKE 'RS'");
echo "\n" . number_format(microtime(true)-$time,6)."\n";

$time = microtime(true);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){$r[]=$row;}
echo "\n" .  number_format(microtime(true)-$time,6);
```

Results:

**With Index: 2.9mS**

```
0.002947 Seconds : $results = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `cities` WHERE `country` LIKE 'RS'");
0.000081 Seconds : while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){$r[]=$row;}
```

**Without Index 93mS**

```
0.093939 Seconds : $results = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `cities` WHERE `country` LIKE 'RS'");
0.000073 Seconds : while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){$r[]=$row;}
```

Then in **phpMyAdmin Profiling**:

```
SET PROFILING = ON;
SELECT *  FROM `cities` WHERE `country` LIKE 'RS';
SHOW PROFILE;
```

Result:
**Execution of the Query took 0.0000003 seconds**

```
starting                0.000020
checking permissions    0.000004
Opening tables          0.000006
init                    0.000007
optimizing              0.000003

executing               0.000003  ******

end                     0.000004
query end               0.000003
closing tables          0.000003
freeing items           0.000010
logging slow query      0.000003
cleaning up             0.000003
```

Without Index
**Execution of the Query took 0.0000012 seconds**

```
starting                0.000046
checking permissions    0.000006
Opening tables          0.000010
init                    0.000021
optimizing              0.000006

executing               0.000012  ******

end                     0.000003
query end               0.000004
closing tables          0.000003
freeing items           0.000017
logging slow query      0.000004
cleaning up             0.000003
```

In phpMyAdmin doing a Search with Profiling turn on
**GoDaddy Server Sending Data   92.6 ms**

```
SELECT *  FROM `cities` WHERE `country` LIKE 'RS' LIMIT 1000
Showing rows 0 - 928 (929 total, Query took 0.0907 sec)
```

Profiling Results:

```
Starting    52 µs
Checking Permissions    7 µs
Opening Tables  23 µs
System Lock     12 µs
Init    34 µs
optimizing  10 µs
Statistics  23 µs
Preparing   17 µs
Executing   4 µs
Sending Data    92.6 ms
End     18 µs
Query End   4 µs
Closing Tables  15 µs
Freeing Items   27 µs
Logging Slow Query  4 µs
Cleaning Up     5 µs
```

In phpMyAdmin doing a Search with Profiling turn on
**On my Server, Sending Data 1.8mS**

```
 SELECT *  FROM `cities` WHERE `country` LIKE 'RS' LIMIT 1000
 Showing rows 0 - 928 (929 total, Query took 0.0022 sec)

    Starting    27 µs
    Checking Permissions    5 µs
    Opening Tables  11 µs
    System Lock     7 µs
    Init    14 µs
    Optimizing  5 µs
    Statistics  43 µs
    Preparing   6 µs
    Executing   2 µs
    Sending Data    1.8 ms
    End     5 µs
    Query End   3 µs
    Closing Tables  5 µs
    Freeing Items   13 µs
    Logging Slow Query  2 µs
    Cleaning Up     2 µs
```

## Just to show the importance of an index.
Over 400x Improvement.

A table with 5,480,942 Records and a Query that Returns 899 Rows

```
$time = microtime(true);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `ipLocations` WHERE `id` = 33644");
echo "\n" . number_format(microtime(true)-$time,6);
$time = microtime(true);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){$r[]=$row;}
echo "\n" .  number_format(microtime(true)-$time,6);
```

**No index**

```
0.402005
0.001264
```

**With Index (426x Faster)**

```
0.001716
0.001962
```

Comment: There is absolutely no possible way you can say that the query should return in "a couple of milliseconds."

Comment: If there is a few KB per line, how long do you think it takes to *transport* 400K rows?

Comment: If you have 400K out of 500K records with isPaperback set to 1, it's almost a certainty that a table scan will be faster than using an index on just the isPaperback column

Comment: I've been doing this for 30 years since the days of dBase II.  Transport and Execute are two different issues.  Just did a query with an index on 5,480,942 records.  Showing rows 0 - 29 (5,480,942 total, Query took 0.0005 sec)

Comment: And those other 400K rows? OP didn't state he just wanted the first 30 rows, so you should consider the transport time too for example. Your "couple of milliseconds" does it. There is no way to say that without any information about the system and the data.

Comment: The query still found  5,480,942 records.  Which means the query took less than a millisecond.  As I stated the trans port and query execution times are two different times.  Take a look at the Profiling results of a query.  For 1000 records the profiler showed Executing  3 µs
Sending Data  569 µs, 500 x .000569 = 0.28 for sending data but the execute will remain not much more than  3 µs.

Comment: @Siyual  No Way?  The numbers do not lie.

Comment: @PatrickHofman  How long does it take to transport?  Certainly not 25 Seconds.  How about 0.0018 Sec for 899 Results out of 5,480,942?  Keeping in mind the OP said "_I also have a BIT field called IsBundle and only 900 records have this set. Again, execution time is about 20-25 seconds."_

Comment: @Aheho Table scan still would not take 25 Seconds.  And what about the 900 `IsBundle` Query?  If a table scan would be faster, the SQL engine would then not use the index and instead use a table scan.

Comment: @Misunderstood, The example query times you have added to you answer really don't tell us much about the original question's scenario. The index helps in your example because it helps the database engine isolate and return only 899 rows out of 5 million. In the questioner's case, he expects 400K rows returned out of 500K.

Comment: I do agree with you that a table scan of 500K rows normally shouldn't take 25 seconds. However we don't know the row size, whether there are any BLOBS or CLOBS columns in the table. It could be old hardware, or there could be a network bandwidth issue as well.

Comment: @Aheho The OP also said _also have a BIT field called IsBundle and only 900 records have this set. Again, execution time is about 20-25 seconds._

Comment: An index would help queries Where IsBundle = 1, but won't help IsPaperback=1. There are other problems at play. Adding and index isn't the answer.

Comment: @Misunderstood Why is this still going...?  Everything I'm seeing here is making a huge assumption that the OP meant the difference between *execution* and *transport*.  When someone says that it took 25 seconds to execute the query, unless they explicitly specify otherwise, I'm going to assume that they mean it took them 25 seconds to retrieve the results.  You're spinning your wheels here for something that is very likely not even a concern to the OP.  I'm standing by my downvote until the OP acknowledges that this is what they meant.